# How to join two pivots in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I m getting the count value and sum in two different pivots. Please guide me how to achieve the both function in a single query.

Count Pivot:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ClaimValue, CurrentBalance, AgeBucket
FROM AR_Claim_Master
WHERE ClientName = 'NXT'
) m
PIVOT (
COUNT(CurrentBalance)
FOR AgeBucket IN ([0-30],[31-60],[61-90],[91-120],[121-210],[>210])
) n
```

Sum Pivot:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ClaimValue, CurrentBalance, AgeBucket
FROM AR_Claim_Master
WHERE ClientName = 'NXT'
) m
PIVOT (
SUM(CurrentBalance)
FOR AgeBucket IN ([0-30],[31-60],[61-90],[91-120],[121-210],[>210])
) n
```

I want the result like this image. Please help me out.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this thru below query...

```
select m1.ClaimValue, 
m1.[0-30] [0-30c], n1.[0-30][0-30v], 
m1.[31-60] [31-60c], n1.[31-60] [31-60v], 
m1.[61-90] [61-90c], n1.[61-90] [61-90v],
m1.[91-120] [91-120c], n1.[91-120] [91-120v],
m1.[121-210] [121-210c], n1.[121-210] [121-210v], 
m1.[>210] [>210c], n1.[>210] [>210v]
from (
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ClaimValue, CurrentBalance, AgeBucket
FROM AR_Claim_Master
WHERE ClientName = 'NXT'
) m
PIVOT (
COUNT(CurrentBalance)
FOR AgeBucket IN ([0-30],[31-60],[61-90],[91-120],[121-210],[>210])
) n
) m1
join 
(
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ClaimValue, CurrentBalance, AgeBucket
FROM AR_Claim_Master
WHERE ClientName = 'NXT'
) m
PIVOT (
SUM(CurrentBalance)
FOR AgeBucket IN ([0-30],[31-60],[61-90],[91-120],[121-210],[>210])
) n 
) n1

on m1.ClaimValue = n1.ClaimValue
order by m1.ClaimValue
```